# Need advice on correct SQL Server multi-column index definition

Tags: sql-server

Our database (SQL Server Azure) is multi-tenant where every row has a six-character tenant ID.  The main transaction table is called LoadTicket and the clustered index is:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_LoadTicket
  ON FWT.dbo.LoadTicket (TenantID, TicketDate DESC)
GO
```

But given that the average tenant produces 120 tickets a day (and some produce more than 1000), would a better index definition be:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_LoadTicket
  ON FWT.dbo.LoadTicket (TicketDate DESC, TenantID)
GO
```

Keep in mind that querying recent results by date and tenant is the most used query in our entire system.    At no time are users able to do any sort of query on this table (or any other table) without the Tenant ID.

Comment: Is there any other unique value? Like a TicketID? Is the only way to reference a specific ticket by the timestamp and the tenant id?

Comment: Each row does have a UID.  This is only used for creation and the occasional update.  Users can query by ticket number but that is not unique to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query is always providing a `TenantId` the first option will result in the fewest reads as all of the records for a `Tenant` will be located on the same page(s) (for the most part)*.

If you need to query all tickets in a given time frame frequently (instead of the occasional ad hoc query) an index on `TicketDate` may help, but that depends on a few things.

If there is another unique key on the table, you can always specify the *unique* clustered index as `(TenantId,TicketDate,<other key column<s>)` but it would produce essentially the same result.

*Over time clustered indexes can fragment (this is done so insert performance isn't affected).  This usually won't impact query performance that much, but if it does you can rebuild or reorganize the clustered index periodically.

Comment: Regarding your first point: in the database as of today there are 4.8 million tickets in the load ticket table spread out across 85 tenants.  In a perfect world, that's 56k tickets per tenant.  However the current production is 10K tickets per Date (all tenants combined) .  So if my most used query is Tenant ID and a single date ("today" is most common), would it not be more efficient to have the Date be the first column in the index?

Comment: No.  You can seek to the the first row for that (Tenant,Day) in both cases.

Comment: What @DavidBrowne-Microsoft said.  Specifying the entirety of the index in the query will produce the same result no matter the order of the columns.  However, `(TenantId,TicketDate)` will product fewer reads if you are searching for a tenant's tickets over a date range.